# Download previous JDK version from Oracle site

Tags: java

How may I download a specific JDK version, 1.6.0_04? On the Oracle site I see only how to load the latest version.  In the [previous version section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/previous-jsp-138793.html) of the Oracle site, I don’t see this version available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full list about half-way down the page [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html): "6 Update 4"